# Running shell script in container when connecting with docker exec

Tags: docker, shell, kubernetes

I would like to run a shell script every time when a shell is started using `docker exec` or `kubectl exec`. I am looking for something similar to `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile`/`.profile`, but since this particular container is based on alpine linux, bash is not available.

How could I execute a shell script in the container?

I would like to achieve something like this:

```bash
> docker exec -it my_alpine_based_container sh
Hi! Welcome to the container. This message comes from a shell script.
/usr/src/app $
```

And similarly with `kubectl`:

```bash
> kubectl exec -it my_pod_running_the_container -- sh
Hi! Welcome to the container. This message comes from a shell script.
/usr/src/app $
```

Comment: What is the main process running in the container?  How would you get a shell inside that process, if it weren't running in Docker?  (I'd reserve `docker exec` for an occasional-use debugging tool, and not particularly try to customize or control its behavior.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the busybox ash variant, which is used by Alpine Linux as well, it is possible to set the ENV variable in the Dockerfile to point to a script that is executed on startup - even for not login shells.

For details see the busybox ash source code: [ash.c, line 14189](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/shell/ash.c?h=1_29_3#n14189).

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
ENV ENV=/root/.ashrc
RUN echo "echo 'Hello from .ashrc!'" >> /root/.ashrc
CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

Test:

```bash
 $ docker exec -it c8688d3e9ce8 sh
Hello from .ashrc!
/ #
```

Answer (score 1):

Alpine linux uses ash for `/bin/sh`. Ash does support `.profile`, but only when running as a login shell.

Here is an example Dockerfile which prints a welcome message:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN echo 'echo foo' >> /root/.profile
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-l"]
```

Here's it in action:

```
$ docker run -it <image name>
foo
ccdae0bb9d59:/#
```

Now, this doesn't fit one of your requirements, because if you run:

```
docker exec -it <container name> sh
```

the message will not print, because it's missing the `-l` option.

> but since this particular container is based on alpine linux, bash is not available.

Bash is a pretty lightweight addition to the image. If you add Bash to your image like this, then it only adds 4.6 MB to the image.

```
RUN apk add bash
```

I would say that's worth it if it makes your service easier to debug.

Comment: Adding a .profile file in the user home and starting a login shell by executing sh -l has solved my issue.